# Why is my Mule Flow doing multiple HTTP requests when its supposed to make only 1?

Tags: spring, http, javabeans, mule

Hi guys i got a simple HTTP mule flow that connects to a 3rd party API using REST for "create user", "create account", "create site"  and so methods.

Thing is that whenever i run my flow, i see it makes multiple requests, why is this happening? Shouldn't be doing only 1 request as the flow goes? Thought in the beginning that it was maybe doing "retries" or something but all the times it gets connected and I get the response quickly.

Should i be adding the flow code? i mean its a very simple mule flow with a

```
 <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8082" doc:name="HTTP"/>
```

And a few string beans with a custom HTTPHTTPS class to make REST connections during the flow (with their api keys, method, url and such)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you calling the HTTP inbound through a browser? In that case, the extra requests are made by the browser when doing the call to the favicon.ico URL to fetch it. If that the case, there's a way to avoid that by using a filter.

Comment: Omg yes, im doing the call from a browser like doing http://localhost:8082 . How can i filter this??? thanks for the reply :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply place the following filter after your HTTP inbound endpoint:

```
<not-filter>
    <wildcard-filter pattern="/favicon.ico"/>
</not-filter>
```